# Why does the Windows Disk Management tool display my partitions as logical?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-management

Firstly, I own an Acer laptop originally having Windows 7, now upgraded to 8.1, & initially had 3 primary partitions (that is *PQSERVICE*, *SYSTEM RESERVED* & *Acer (C:)*). I decided to migrate my personal data to a dedicated partition, so I used the *Disk Management* utility to shrink some volume from *Acer (C:)*. Then I made *PQSERVICE* & the newly created partitions logical whereas *Acer (C:)* & *SYSTEM RESERVED* were supposed to remain primary. This is how it appears in *EaseUS Partition Master*:

[image]

Pretty much like in *MiniTool Partition Wizard*:

[image]

However, that's not the case for the *Disk Management* tool as it considers both of them as logical:

[image]

Apparently, what the Windows Disk Management tool is displaying is more trustworthy as, whilst I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto the free unformatted partition, it doesn't seem to detect all the logical partitions & considers the whole drive as a single partition. It might as well have something to do with the MBR/GPT issue (I've got MBR if I'm not mistaken).

1. Is it the problem which makes Ubuntu think there are no partitions on the drive?
2. Either way, is it possible to fix that i.e. to make those partitions 'genuinely' primary, so that Windows Disk Management tool believe that?

Comment: From the way its UI is designed, I guess LDM either can't comprehend mixed logical/primary partitions, or can't properly visualize them. What does `fdisk -l` show in Ubuntu?

Comment: @grawity , http://i.imgur.com/RSJk2Si.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that had the PQSERVICE partition been made logical, the extended partition overlapped everything up to the sector 1985, thus making all partitions logical. I converted PQSERVICE back to primary & it now works like a charm: Disk Management sees both the System & the Acer (C:) partition as primary & Ubuntu had no problem to detect all the volumes.

Just in case someone else faces a similar problem.